# Why is my form validator working incorrectly

Tags: php, forms

I am having this kind of problem and I really dont know why, I recently enrolled into php but even tho I don't see any reasson here, why is it not working.

I am using XAMPP apache, php on my computer, I've made several of simple form validators but this one is not working and I am kind of desperate here. All of the code below is in one `index.php` file which I am opening via localhost link in my browser. When I open it code is like this:

> Array ( ) no error

and then form. Once I click submit without filling ANY data into form, it refreshes and this is what appears:

> Array ( [email] => [password] => ) no error

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php 
    print_r($_POST);
    if(array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)){

        $err = "";

        if(!$_POST["email"]){
            $err = "You need to type in email";
        } else if(!$_POST["password"]){
            $err = "You need to type in password";
        }   

    }
    if($err = ""){
        echo $err."tak";
    }else{
        echo "no error";
    }
?>
<div id="error"><? php echo $err ?></div>
<form method="post" >

    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="email">

    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password">

    <input type="checkbox" name="StayLoggedIn" value="1">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Comment: And what do you expect to see? Also, do you know the difference between `=` and `==`?

Comment: The submit button will not send up a value because it is lacking a `name` attribute. It is the submit button's name that you would be checking not 'submit' unless 'submit' happened to be the name.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to send "submit" key, it's useless actually.
All you need to make it work is remove that "if" condition:

```
if(array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)){
```

because you can just grab data if it exists (email and password).
Also you can improve your code like this:

```
$err = "no error";

if(!$_POST["email"]){
    $err = "You need to type in email";
} else if(!$_POST["password"]){
    $err = "You need to type in password";
}
```

and delete unnecessary "if-else" checks at the end. 
Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Ive got it, nobody noticed that i have `if ($err == "")`, yes i had only `if ($err = "")` but the point was it was always false because i always had one or two fields empty i was missing an `!` point there and all would have been fine. Oh and yes ive missed the `name` property with submit input too. But iam very grateful guys!

This is the final working code

```
<?php 
    print_r($_POST);
    if(array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)){

        $error = "";

        if(!($_POST['email']) ){
            $error.="You need to type in email";
        } 

        if(!$_POST["password"]){
            $error.="You need to type in password";
        }   


    }

?>
<div id="error"><?php echo $error ?></div>
<form method="post" >

    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="email">

    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password">

    <input type="checkbox" name="StayLoggedIn" value="1">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Does is better `if(!isset($_POST["email"])){ $error.="You need to type in email"; }` ?